# How to extract the column names which doesn't have any null values in a dataset in r/sparklyr?

Tags: r, sparklyr

I want to extract only the column names that doesn't have null values in  a large dataset in r.

If my table has 4 columns (id, Price, Product, Status) with columns Price and Status having a few null values and columns id and Product with no null values. Then I would want my output as: id, Product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need an exact answer you'll have to scan full dataset first, to count missing values:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- copy_to(sc, tibble(
  id = 1:4,  Price = c(NA, 3.20, NA, 42),
  Product = c("p1", "p2", "p3", "p4"),
  Status = c(NA, "foo", "bar", NA)))

null_counts <- df %>% 
    summarise_all(funs(sum(as.numeric(is.na(.)), na.rm=TRUE))) %>% 
    collect() 

null_counts
```

```
# A tibble: 1 x 4
     id Price Product Status
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1     0     2       0      2
```

determine which columns have missing count equal to zero:

```
cols_without_nulls <- null_counts %>% 
  select_if(funs(. == 0)) %>% 
  colnames()

cols_without_nulls
```

```
[1] "id"      "Product"
```

and use these to select

```
df %>% select(one_of(cols_without_nulls))
```

```
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 2]
     id Product
  <int> <chr>  
1     1 p1     
2     2 p2     
3     3 p3     
4     4 p4
```

A shorter variant exists:

```
df %>% select_if(funs(sum(as.numeric(is.na(.)), na.rm=TRUE) == 0))
```

```
Applying predicate on the first 100 rows
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 2]
     id Product
  <int> <chr>  
1     1 p1     
2     2 p2     
3     3 p3     
4     4 p4
```

but as you see it will only sample the data.

Answer (score -1):

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4),
                   Price = c(50, NA, 10, 20),
                   Product = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                   Status = c("Complete", NA, "Complete", "Incomplete"))

names(apply(data, 2, anyNA)[apply(data, 2, anyNA) == FALSE])
```